# error while including external JARs in ant script

Tags: java, ant

This is my first attempt at writing an ANT script. This is my build.xml for a simple Hello World app using Spring.

```
<project name="MyFirstApp" default="jar" basedir="..">  
    <property name="src" location="src"/>
    <property name="build" location="build"/>
    <property name="lib" location="/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib"/>   
    <path id="classpath-example">   
        <fileset dir="${build}" includes="*.jar"/>
    </path>
    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="build"/>
    </target>
    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="build/classes"/>
        <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="build/classes" includeantruntime="false"/>
        <classpath refid="classpath-example"/>
    </target>
    <target name="jar">
        <mkdir dir="build/jar"/>
        <jar destfile="build/jar/MyFirstApp.jar" basedir="build/classes"/>          
    </target>
    <target name="run">
        <java jar="build/jar/MyFirstApp.jar" fork="true"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

when i try to run this the following error message is displayed.

Problem: failed to create task or type classpath
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any / declarations have taken place.

Can someone please tell me what is to be done?

The first time i ran the ANT script, the JAR file was generated. When i tried running it again , it gives the below mentioned error.

clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory F:\shil\JAVA\Spring Workspace\myfirstapp1\build

```
compile:
     [echo] compiling
    [mkdir] Created dir: F:\shil\JAVA\Spring Workspace\myfirstapp1\build\classes

    [javac] Compiling 5 source files to F:\shil\JAVA\Spring Workspace\myfirstapp
1\build\classes
    [javac] F:\shil\JAVA\Spring Workspace\myfirstapp1\src\my\hello\servlet\Hello
WorldServlet.java:4: package javax.servlet does not exist
    [javac] import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac] F:\shil\JAVA\Spring Workspace\myfirstapp1\src\my\hello\servlet\Hello
WorldServlet.java:5: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
    [javac] import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac] F:\shil\JAVA\Spring Workspace\myfirstapp1\src\my\hello\servlet\Hello
WorldServlet.java:6: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
    [javac] import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac] F:\shil\JAVA\Spring Workspace\myfirstapp1\src\my\hello\servlet\Hello
WorldServlet.java:7: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
    [javac] import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac] F:\shil\JAVA\Spring Workspace\myfirstapp1\src\my\hello\servlet\Hello
WorldServlet.java:12: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol: class HttpServlet
    [javac] public class HelloWorldServlet extends HttpServlet {
    [javac]                                        ^
    [javac] F:\shil\JAVA\Spring Workspace\myfirstapp1\src\my\hello\servlet\Hello
WorldServlet.java:26: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class HttpServletRequest
    [javac] location: class my.hello.servlet.HelloWorldServlet
    [javac]     protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResp
onse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac] F:\shil\JAVA\Spring Workspace\myfirstapp1\src\my\hello\servlet\Hello
WorldServlet.java:26: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class HttpServletResponse
    [javac] location: class my.hello.servlet.HelloWorldServlet
    [javac]     protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResp
onse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    [javac]                                                      ^
    [javac] F:\shil\JAVA\Spring Workspace\myfirstapp1\src\my\hello\servlet\Hello
WorldServlet.java:26: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ServletException
    [javac] location: class my.hello.servlet.HelloWorldServlet
    [javac]     protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResp
onse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    [javac]
                      ^
    [javac] F:\shil\JAVA\Spring Workspace\myfirstapp1\src\my\hello\servlet\Hello
WorldServlet.java:33: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class HttpServletRequest
    [javac] location: class my.hello.servlet.HelloWorldServlet
    [javac]     protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletRes
ponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    [javac]                           ^
    [javac] F:\shil\JAVA\Spring Workspace\myfirstapp1\src\my\hello\servlet\Hello
WorldServlet.java:33: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class HttpServletResponse
    [javac] location: class my.hello.servlet.HelloWorldServlet
    [javac]     protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletRes
ponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    [javac]                                                       ^
    [javac] F:\shil\JAVA\Spring Workspace\myfirstapp1\src\my\hello\servlet\Hello
WorldServlet.java:33: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ServletException
    [javac] location: class my.hello.servlet.HelloWorldServlet
    [javac]     protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletRes
ponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    [javac]
                       ^
    [javac] F:\shil\JAVA\Spring Workspace\myfirstapp1\src\my\hello\servlet\Welco
meServlet.java:4: package javax.servlet does not exist
    [javac] import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac] F:\shil\JAVA\Spring Workspace\myfirstapp1\src\my\hello\servlet\Welco
meServlet.java:5: package javax.servlet does not exist
    [javac] import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac] F:\shil\JAVA\Spring Workspace\myfirstapp1\src\my\hello\servlet\Welco
meServlet.java:6: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
    [javac] import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac] F:\shil\JAVA\Spring Workspace\myfirstapp1\src\my\hello\servlet\Welco
meServlet.java:7: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
    [javac] import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac] F:\shil\JAVA\Spring Workspace\myfirstapp1\src\my\hello\servlet\Welco
meServlet.java:8: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
    [javac] import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac] F:\shil\JAVA\Spring Workspace\myfirstapp1\src\my\hello\servlet\Welco
meServlet.java:15: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol: class HttpServlet
    [javac] public class WelcomeServlet extends HttpServlet {
    [javac]                                     ^
    [javac] F:\shil\JAVA\Spring Workspace\myfirstapp1\src\my\hello\servlet\Welco
meServlet.java:29: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class HttpServletRequest
    [javac] location: class my.hello.servlet.WelcomeServlet
    [javac]     protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResp
onse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac] F:\shil\JAVA\Spring Workspace\myfirstapp1\src\my\hello\servlet\Welco
meServlet.java:29: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class HttpServletResponse
    [javac] location: class my.hello.servlet.WelcomeServlet
    [javac]     protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResp
onse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    [javac]                                                      ^
    [javac] F:\shil\JAVA\Spring Workspace\myfirstapp1\src\my\hello\servlet\Welco
meServlet.java:29: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ServletException
    [javac] location: class my.hello.servlet.WelcomeServlet
    [javac]     protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResp
onse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    [javac]
                      ^
    [javac] F:\shil\JAVA\Spring Workspace\myfirstapp1\src\my\hello\servlet\Welco
meServlet.java:36: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class HttpServletRequest
    [javac] location: class my.hello.servlet.WelcomeServlet
    [javac]     protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletRes
ponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    [javac]                           ^
    [javac] F:\shil\JAVA\Spring Workspace\myfirstapp1\src\my\hello\servlet\Welco
meServlet.java:36: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class HttpServletResponse
    [javac] location: class my.hello.servlet.WelcomeServlet
    [javac]     protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletRes
ponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    [javac]                                                       ^
    [javac] F:\shil\JAVA\Spring Workspace\myfirstapp1\src\my\hello\servlet\Welco
meServlet.java:36: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ServletException
    [javac] location: class my.hello.servlet.WelcomeServlet
    [javac]     protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletRes
ponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    [javac]
                       ^
    [javac] F:\shil\JAVA\Spring Workspace\myfirstapp1\src\my\hello\servlet\Welco
meServlet.java:41: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class RequestDispatcher
    [javac] location: class my.hello.servlet.WelcomeServlet
    [javac]             RequestDispatcher welcomeDispatcher = getServletContext(
).getRequestDispatcher("/Welcome.jsp");
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] F:\shil\JAVA\Spring Workspace\myfirstapp1\src\my\hello\servlet\Welco
meServlet.java:41: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : method getServletContext()
    [javac] location: class my.hello.servlet.WelcomeServlet
    [javac]             RequestDispatcher welcomeDispatcher = getServletContext(
).getRequestDispatcher("/Welcome.jsp");
    [javac]                                                   ^
    [javac] Note: F:\shil\JAVA\Spring Workspace\myfirstapp1\src\my\hello\HelloWo
rldApp.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    [javac] 25 errors

BUILD FAILED
F:\shil\JAVA\Spring Workspace\myfirstapp1\ant\build.xml:19: Compile failed; see
the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 1 second
```

why did this not happen the first time? can someone please help?

Answer (score 5):

The `<classpath>` inside your `compile` target should be nested inside the `<javac>` element.

It's also worth noting that a lot of the power of ant (and, indeed, most build systems) comes from declaring dependencies between targets. In your example, it doesn't make any sense to run the `jar` target without first having run the `compile` target, otherwise, there are no class files to jar - or worse, you'll run `jar` by hand, but forget to run `compile` first and end up with out-of-date classes in your JAR file. So, the `jar` target should depend on the `compile` target. That way, whenever you run the `jar` target, any changed class will automatically be compiled first. Similarly, the `run` target should depend on the `jar` target.

Comment: or you can simply define a classpath variable outside the target, like this. This is more elegant.   <path id="classpath">
    <pathelement location="../project/classes"/>
    <pathelement location="${my.lib}abc.jar"/>
  </path>

Comment: It looks like the OP is trying to reference an pre-defined classpath that his compilation depends on.

Answer (score 0):

Use classpathref attribute instead like this

```
<javac path="src" destdir="build/classes" classpathref="classpath-example"/>
```