# build.xml javac is complaining about missing classes from javax.servlet.http during compliation

Tags: java, xml, tomcat, netbeans, ant

I've written a [build.xml](http://pastebin.com/f8HwPG8z) (*Updated 8:49 PM*) for a netbeans project. And I've found that the tomcat libraries such as `serlvet-api.jar` are in the directory `C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.35\lib`. But I'm not sure how I'm meant to connect the `target="class_compile"` using the `fieldset dir` to the tomcat directory (without changing the build.xml each time I wish to compile from another computer).

I've read the question [error while including external JARs in ant script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7453652/error-while-including-external-jars-in-ant-script), with the solution being a missing `classpathref` attribute within the `javac` element (although my `classpathref` attribute seems to be correct).

```
<path id="build.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
        <include name="**/*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>

<target name="class_compile" depends="prepare" description="Compile the whole project">
    <javac destdir="${build.classes}" 
            debug="${debug}" 
            deprecation="on"
            optimize="off"
            srcdir="${src.dir}"
            classpathref="build.classpath"
            includes="*/**"
    />
    <copy todir="${build.classes}">
        <fileset dir="${src.dir}" includes="**/*.properties"/>
    </copy>
</target>

<target name="prepare">
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${build.classes}"/>
    <path id="run.classpath" >
        <pathelement location="${build.classes}" />
    </path>
    <mkdir dir="${build.lib}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${qa.dir}"/>
</target>
```

Currently, once the `class_compile` target is executed multiple errors regarding missing class files are reported..

```
emma:
Created dir: C:\capstonegroup3\TTTserver\build\emma-instr
Created dir: C:\capstonegroup3\TTTserver\build\emma-reports
prepare:
Created dir: C:\capstonegroup3\TTTserver\build\classes
Created dir: C:\capstonegroup3\TTTserver\build\lib
Created dir: C:\capstonegroup3\TTTserver\build\qa-reports
class_compile:
C:\capstonegroup3\TTTserver\build.xml:152: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
Compiling 21 source files to C:\capstonegroup3\TTTserver\build\classes
C:\capstonegroup3\TTTserver\src\java\AuthServer\AuthenticationInterface.java:8: error: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
```

Is there any way to set a `property` to the `tomcat apache/lib` directory, from persay a `.property` file? I saw in my `build_impl.xml` (generated by netbeans, that has a property file included during the `-init-private` target).

```
<target depends="-pre-init" name="-init-private">
    <property file="nbproject/private/private.properties"/>
</target>
```

But I'm unsure how to gain access to those properties for my `build.xml`. But basically I'm after a solution that generates a relative path to the `apache-tomcat\lib` directory, and successfully compiles the class files without missing packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare the servlet-api.jar file to build.classpath as below

```
<path id="build.classpath">
    <fileset dir="C:/apache-tomcat-7.0.35/lib">
        <include name="servlet-api.jar" />
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
        <include name="**/*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>
```

Comment: Preferably as stated within the question, I would like a solution that is for a `relative` path. Your suggestion seems to be more of an `absolute` path, solution.

Comment: If you want a relative path, you should copy the "servlet-api.jar" file to ${lib.dir} folder.

*Remember delete that file from build lib when you run project on tomcat

Answer (score 2):

What I like to do is keep a `local.properties` file that describes my local environment in the parent folder of the project folder (e.g. under NetBeansProjects), e.g.:

```
NetBeansProjects
+- local.properties
+- MyProject
   +- build.xml
   +- <other stuff>
```

The `build.xml` is like:

```
tomcat.home=/C:/java/tomcat
gwt.dir=/C:/java/google/gwt-2.5.1
```

This file is not kept under version control and allows each developer to configure his/her own environment. It is read by Ant using something like:

```
<property file="../local.properties" />
```

And used e.g. as (this is only an example, adjust for proper usage):

```
<path id="project.classpath">
    <pathelement path="war/WEB-INF/classes" />
    <fileset dir="war/WEB-INF/lib">
        <include name="*.jar" />
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="${tomcat.home}/lib"><!-- tomcat.home defined in local.properties -->
        <include name="**/*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising I'll try it out :).